# tfsmigrator organization (dryrun) created in azure devops cannot delete

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-migration

I have migrated 2 collections from TFS 2018 to Azure Devops successfully using the tfsMigrator and created 2 dryrun orgs.

Since the orgs are automatically deleted after 2 weeks, I would like to create a permanent org so that we can work on creating the CI/CD pipelines and they will not be deleted.

When I run the tfsMigrator to import a collection again as a prodrun (to make it permanent), I get the following error:

[Info   @10:25:19.490] Import couldn't be started due to an error!
[Error  @10:25:19.490] + [Error] VS403256: Organization 'MyTest-run1-dryrun' should be deleted prior to starting this import.

So I tried to delete the org in devops according to these instructions from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/delete-your-organization?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav

However, no delete button shows up in organization settings, so the org cannot be deleted.
My question is how can I delete this org so I can make a permanent one to work on?  Also, when it comes time to import live data from TFS, will I run into the same issue?